# How to send a request payload that includes [ ]

Tags: c#, post, httpwebrequest, payload

I have to call a webservice and when I used google tools, I saw the request payload and it looks like this:

```
[text%20search]
```

my code currently is doing the following:

```
using (Stream streamWriter = chttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                string postdata = "[text%20search]";
                byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata);
                streamWriter.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }
```

But I'm getting a 502 error, and I'm guessing this might be related to the way I'm sending the POST data to the service.

Can someone please point me in the right direction on this? Thanks in advance!